# Find keep duplicates in Ruby hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes where I need to find and store matches based on one matching value between the hashes.

```
a = [{:id => 1, :name => "Jim", :email => "jim@jim.jim"}, 
     {:id => 2, :name => "Paul", :email => "paul@paul.paul"}, 
     {:id => 3, :name => "Tom", :email => "tom@tom.tom"}, 
     {:id => 1, :name => "Jim", :email => "jim@jim.jim"}, 
     {:id => 5, :name => "Tom", :email => "tom@tom.tom"}, 
     {:id => 6, :name => "Jim", :email => "jim@jim.jim"}]
```

So I would want to return

```
b = [{:id => 1, :name => "Jim", :email => "jim@jim.jim"},  
     {:id => 3, :name => "Tom", :email => "tom@tom.tom"}, 
     {:id => 5, :name => "Tom", :email => "tom@tom.tom"}, 
     {:id => 6, :name => "Jim", :email => "jim@jim.jim"}]
```

Notes: I can sort the data (csv) by `:name` after the fact so they don't have to be nicely grouped, just accurate. Also it's not necessary two of the same, it could be 3 or 10 or more.

Also, the data is about 22,000 rows.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to do is the opposite of `uniq!` but I haven't been able to figure out exactly how to process that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I tested this and it will do exactly what you want:

```
b = a.group_by { |h| h[:name] }.values.select { |a| a.size > 1 }.flatten
```

However, you might want to look at some of the intermediate objects produced in that calculation and see if those are more useful to you.

Comment: I tested this and as you said it works great! Thanks so much for the lightening fast response.

Comment: If you're looking for extra credit, and to make a very tired person happy, what if I need to remove instances where `:id` was the same? Meaning keep only records where `:email` is the same but `:id` is different.

Comment: By email do you mean `name`?  If two records have the same name and id, then the hashes should be equal, so I would simply put `a.uniq!` on its own line above my code.  Or you could insert `.uniq` right before `.group_by`.

Comment: Apologies; no, the real hash is larger with 8 keys. I need to find duplicates where the `:id` isn't the same so they can be combined. I've updated the original question to a better approximation of the data.