# How to find duplicate records in ActiveRecord other than original one

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Using Rails 4, Ruby 2, MySql

I would like to find all the records in my database which are repeats of another record - but not the original record itself.

This is so I can `update_attributes(:duplicate => true)` on each of these records and leave the original one not marked as a duplicate.

You could say that I am looking for the opposite of `Uniq`* I don't want the Uniq values, I want all the values which are not uniq after the fact. I don't want all values which have a duplicate as that would include the original.

I don't mind using pure SQL or Ruby for this but I would prefer to use active record to keep it Railsy.

Let's say the table is called "Leads" and we are looking for those where the field "telephone_number" is the same. I would leave record 1 alone and mark 2,3 and 4 as duplicate = true.

`*` If I wanted the opposite of Uniq I could do something like [Find keep duplicates in Ruby hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222456/find-keep-duplicates-in-ruby-hashes)

`b = a.group_by { |h| h[:telephone_number] }.values.select { |a| a.size > 1 }.flatten`

But that is all the records, I want all the duplicated ones other than the original one I'm comparing it to.

Comment: are you planning on deleting these duplicates? because there's certainly SQL out there for removing duplicates

Comment: No, I'm keeping them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your query returns all 'Leads' that have the same telephone number in an array b.   You can then use

`b = b.shift`

which takes the first element off of the b array.  Then you can continue with your original thought `update_attributes(:duplicate => true)`

Comment: Sorry I just fixed a typo, it's b.shift, not shift(b).  As long as you can get all of the records into an array, this should work.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's something I had never really considered doing before today.