# Shift not working after upgrading rails to 4.1. Attempting to remove first item from array. No longer getting array to use shift on

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a rake task which was working in rails 4.0 but now I've upgraded to 4.1 this no longer works. Now I get an error about calling shift

```
undefined method `shift' for #<CallBackRequest::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x007f9e5b9fb630>
```

The Rake

```
instructors.each do |instructor|
   print "#{instructor.instructor_name} Call Back Request Report \n"
   pupil_leads = instructor.call_back_requests.from_to_bill(2.weeks.ago, 1.week.ago).all
   print "Found #{pupil_leads.count} Call Back Requests for period 2 weeks ago until 1 week ago.\n\n"
   pupil_leads.group_by { |h| h[:telephone_number] }.values.select { |a| a.size > 1 }
   pupil_leads.shift
    if pupil_leads.length > 0
      print "Found #{pupil_leads.count} duplicate CBRs. Proceeding to mark as non billable and resolved..\n\n\n"
      pupil_leads.each do |dpl|
        print "updating this pupil lead #{dpl.inspect}"
        dpl.update_attributes(:billable => false, :resolved => true)
      end
   end
end
```

My understanding is that Rails no longer allows you to call methods on Active Record relations OR Rails doesn't generate an array at some point when it used to, instead keeping the Active Record relation until later. Either way you'd think that there would be a way to acieve this in 4.1 that only involves popping in something like `.all` or another from the `.select .all .pluck .take` range of methods for selecting records. I've tried several things to no avail. Thought I was operating with an array anyway as I have `.all` in my inital `pupil_leads` line.

Aside: I asked this [How to find duplicate records in ActiveRecord other than original one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430049/how-to-find-duplicate-records-in-activerecord-other-than-original-one) a month ago, that's why I'm using shift to remove the first from the array so I can mark all others as duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in Rails >= 4.0 even after you call `all` on relation, it isn't converted to array object. If you really need 'pure' array, you have to do it manually, calling `to_a`.

Comment: as in `pupil_leads = instructor.call_back_requests.from_to_bill(2.weeks.ago, 1.week.ago).all.to_a` ok, seems as simple as I thought it would be.

Comment: @LpLrich you don't need to call `all` here, BTW.

Comment: I had previously tried adding the line `pupil_leads.to_a` before `pupil_leads.shift` with no luck, so I am assuming I should do it where Rails 4.0 did it - ie - at the `.all`

Comment: Yeah, I only needed to call .all there before as I needed it to be an array. You're saying just swap out .all for .to_a